# From Azure Web Role, check if a process is running in worker role

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-cloud-services

I am trying to use

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName, workerRoleIPAddress);
```

From my controller to check if a certain process is running in my worker role. What is the correct IPAddress to use for the worker role? Using the IPAddress that the Input Endpoitns use doesn't seem to work.
Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved the problem by using an Azure Storage table.
I queried the worker role locally using GetProcesssByName() and stored the result in an Azure Storage table. I subsequently accessed this table from the web role to read the result. 
Care must be taken to delete the older entries from the storage table so we don't assume that older(and currently non-existent) processes are still running.

Answer (score 0):

You are not forced to use the second parameter. There are two method signatures:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

- `public static Process[] GetProcessesByName(string);`
- `public static Process[] GetProcessesByName(string, string);`

I suggest you try to get clear with the first method signature. After, try to use the IP address.

I would try 127.0.0.1 first. This is the shortest way to try. Maybe even 'localhost' would be working.

Then, I don't know this precise in detail, but to ask a process list on a distant computer, this method will need some service running on the distant computer. So there might be firewall ports need to be opened opened or a certain demon need to be running on the other computer. Asking a list of processes on a distant computer will quickly become a security issue.